# reader-writer lock in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Is there any implementation of reader writer lock in Elixir? Or other solution?

In my OTP, N reader processes and 1 writer process share a state. The writer need 3 seconds to fully update the shared state. The readers may get dirty data when updating. The state is stored in Redis and ElasticSearch rather than ETS. Since the frequency of reading is much higher than that of writing, I want to keep read performance while avoiding dirty-read.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With redis, you could use a "double buffer" approach. The writer writes to its own key(s), which readers don't read from. They read from "completed" version of the keys. When writer is done writing/updating, it atomically renames its dirty keys to completed. Not sure if ES can do this.

Comment: Double buffer works for single Redis. What should I do if readers must wait for both Redis and ES to be updated before reading?